# Duplicate messages in Flink kafka sink from Source kafka CDC using table connectors

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I'm trying to use Apache Flink 1.15.1 to read messages from two kafka topic, transform them and finally send them to another kafka topic. Added some savepoints to save the state of the application in case of cancellation and restating. The problem is that we are getting duplicate messages in the topic after restart.
For example if we have 10 message in topic after job run and we restart the job again then we are seeing 20 msgs in topic. Please help me on this.

```
            EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build();
            TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);          
            Configuration configuration = tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration();
            configuration.setString("restart-strategy", "fixed-delay");
            configuration.setString("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts", "3");
            configuration.setString("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay", "30s");
            configuration.setString("execution.checkpointing.mode", "EXACTLY_ONCE");
            configuration.setString("execution.checkpointing.interval", "3min");
            configuration.setString("execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention", "DELETE_ON_CANCELLATION");
            configuration.setString("state.backend", "rocksdb");
            configuration.setString("state.checkpoints.dir", "file:///tmp/checkpoints/");
            
            String statement = "CREATE TABLE test1 (\r\n" + 
                    "  id STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  sameAs STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED\r\n" + 
                    ") WITH (\r\n" + 
                    "  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',\r\n" + 
                    "  'topic' = 'source4',\r\n" + 
                    "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" + 
                    "  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-cp-schema-registry:8081'\r\n" + 
                    ")";
            
            tEnv.executeSql(statement);
            
            String relStatement = "CREATE TABLE test2 (\r\n" + 
                    "  id STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  correlationId STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  ),\r\n" + 
                    "  PRIMARY KEY (correlationId) NOT ENFORCED\r\n" + 
                    ") WITH (\r\n" + 
                    "  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',\r\n" + 
                    "  'topic' = 'relationship4',\r\n" + 
                    "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" + 
                    "  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-cp-schema-registry:8081'\r\n" + 
                    ")";
            tEnv.executeSql(relStatement);

            /*sink1*/
             tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE test3 (\n" +
                        "  id STRING,\r\n" + 
                        "  roleId STRING,\r\n" + 
                        "  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED\r\n" + 
                        ") WITH (\n" +
                        "  'connector'  = 'upsert-kafka',\n" +
                        "  'topic' = 'test4',\r\n" + 
                        "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" + 
                        "  'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',\r\n" + 
                        "  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" + 
                        "  'value.format' = 'json'\r\n" + 
                        ")");       

             String joinStat = "INSERT INTO test3 select............. "          
             tEnv.executeSql(joinStat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any configuration for exactly once guarantees setup with Kafka, so  you will get at-least-guarantees per https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#consistency-guarantees

On the same page you can also find that you'll need to add `sink.delivery-guarantee` and `sink.transactional-id-prefix` if you want to achieve exactly-once guarantees.

Comment: As we are using 'upsert-kafka'  so if add this `sink.delivery-guarantee` and  `sink.transactional-id-prefix` we are getting error as invalid options